# Expanding the dimension of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a thumbnail. When i click on it, how can i enlarge it. I know there are many plugins that do this, but is there simple code that serve the purpose.

Comment: Define "enlarge it". Do you mean just give it large dimensions? Or swap it with another, fullsized version?

Comment: enlarge dimensions from all sides..usually when the image is enlarged it is done from the right and bottom..i want to enlarge from all sides

Comment: Why not use a plugin? What's the use of reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a lightbox type scenario where the image pops up in front of the content, that's not possible with simple code. You'll need a plugin like [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) for that.

If you're talking about simply changing the dimensions of an image, you can do something like this:

```
$('#img1').width(500).height(500); // Change "500" to whatever size you want.
```